# Parallel element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following situation:

```
<ul>
    <li>Button 1</li>
    <li class="active">Button 2</li>
    <li>Button 3</li>
    <li>Button 4</li>
</ul>
```

now the following code that handles it:

```
    $('.tab-menu li').on('click', function() {
        $($($(this).closest('.tab-menu')).find('li')).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

it works, but is there a jQuery function that selects all 'parallel' elements ? I want this 
part

```
$($($(this).closest('.tab-menu')).find('li')).removeClass('active');
```

make shorter. I know 'toggleClass', but this works only on the clicked element. Is there any shorter method to select all parallel elements? (In this siutation all 'li' that belongs to the specific 'ul');

Comment: Isn't that entire first part redundant? `$($(this).closest('.tab-menu')).find('li'))` is already `this`

Comment: no it will be a list of all the `li`'s under `.tab-menu` not just the one currently being iterated over

Comment: @DGS But he iterates over all of them.  It's nonsensical code.

Comment: You don't need to keep recasting things to jquery objects (the `$($($(`).  Nearly all jquery functions return jquery objects.  The only one that I know of which does not is `get` which is explicitly for getting the dom element out of the jquery object.

Comment: this is my mistake, I iterate cuz I want to assign an event listener to every iterated object.

Comment: @OskarSzura Should the code above really say `each`??

Comment: No, it doesn't - but it's a development version only - I'm aware of this.

Comment: @OskarSzura We can only help fix problems in the real code.  If this is not it then please post the correct version.

Comment: The add class in the each does not make any sense at all, basically you are setting the class on every element. What is the real code?

Comment: here You go (the code has been edited), but the below answer is enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, using [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r9W/1/) with onclick